# Plotting solutions to NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages

Working through some problems of the book [A Physicists guide to Mathematica](https://www.elsevier.com/books/a-physicists-guide-to-mathematica/tam/978-0-12-683192-4). I'm getting the following errors when I try and plot the solution over a certain range. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Also include copy-able code in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to evaluate `y[t]` by the solution you've found, not the differential equation!

```
sol=NDSolve[...]

Plot[Evaluate[y[t]/.sol], ...]
```

Comment: Of course!!! Time for a coffee... I was wondering why I was getting these errors... I had gone through multiple this morning and getting great results! I will accept once it allows me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the help [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) on `NDSolve`.

The interpolation function and its derivative can be plotted like this,

```
eqn = y''[t] == Sin[t]*y[t] + t

sol = NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], y'[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If you need, then you can also plot `y[t]` vs `y'[t]` using `ParametricPlot`,

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{y[t], y'[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]