# Problem about solve a 1st order simultaneous differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I read this article “Khan, A. I. et al. Nat. Mater. 14, 182-186 (2015)”, part of which simulates the transient behavior of circuit with nonlinear capacitance under effect of voltage profile Vs. Corresponded differential equations and simulation results are captured below.

[image]

The simultaneous equations are in integral form, which is difficult to me. So I change the physical quantity from current to charge.

[image]

The results end with a 1st order simultaneous differential equations. I have attempted to solve QR, QC and QF in a function of time but an error appeared.
I don’t know what is going on…Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
R = 50000;
ρ = 50000;
CP = 60*10^-12;
doverA = (60*10^-9)/(900*10^-12);
α = -8.071*10^7*doverA;
β = 2.23043*10^8*doverA;
γ = 3.55986*10^8*doverA;
VS = 5.*(2*(UnitStep[t - 400*(10^-6)] - UnitStep[t - 800*(10^-6)]) - 1);
Vint = 2*α*D[Qf[t], t] + 4*β*( D[Qf[t], t])^3 + 6*γ*(D[Qf[t], t])^5;

eq1 = VS - D[Qr[t], t] R - (D[Qr[t], t] - D[Qc[t], t]) ρ - Vint;
eq2 = Vint + (D[Qr[t], t] - D[Qc[t], t]) ρ - Qc[t]/CP;
eq3 = D[Qf[t], t] == D[Qr[t], t] - D[Qc[t], t];
InitialCondition = {Qr[0] == 0, Qc[0] == 0, Qf[0] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3, InitialCondition}, {Qr[t], Qc[t], Qf[t]}, {t, 0, 1200*(10^-6)}]
```

Comment: Add to `NDSolve` option: ```Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}```.

Comment: Can't reproduce the warning in _v8_, _v9_, _v11.2_. Which version are you in?

Comment: My version is v10.3.1. I have successfully skip the `NDSolve:ndcf` by add `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`. However, I can not plot the results by use `Plot[Qr[t],{t,0,1200*10^-6}]`.

Comment: The result is an empty graph.

Comment: @user47724 The solutions calculated by `NDSolve` are not automatically assigned to the function name. You need to provide `Plot` with the value of `Q[t]` from your calculated solutions. Try: `Plot[Evaluate[Qr[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1200*10^-6}]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting solutions to NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139199/27951).

Comment: Thanks! I can now plot the result although there is a slight difference compared to what the article shows. 
https://i.imgur.com/GaVmQCS.png
But I thick it is not technical problem. I will check all the parameters I set.